# Eclipse: find lines in a block that can throw exceptions

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, exception

I'm looking at code that looks like

```
try {
     // Lots of things here.
     // More than I'd like to individually hover over every time I see this
} 
catch (Exception e) {
     // doesn't matter
}
```

For any particular method in the try block, I can find what checked exceptions it throws. Is there any way to highlight all lines that could throw some checked exception?

In general, I guess I could perhaps remove the catch block, changing the method signature to throw Exception, at which point, I can see all lines in the method that throw an exception (Nevermind: see the update).

In this case, that won't even work nicely, because the code is in a JSP.

Note: if it matters, I'm using MyEclipse standard.

Update: Mark occurrences is on, but simply does nothing in this case. I asked the question because I thought that something about the context made this expected behavior, but it looks like it's a weird edge case or bug.

Comment: If you remove the try/catch block Eclipse will highlight all checked exceptions as an error (you are required to catch them, it won't compile). To the best of my knowledge the feature depends on the compile errors but I'd have to dig into the source to find that out. Assuming it is **not** based on compile errors you could hook that into the editor. It is a good idea for a feature, however the way I handle it is to simply inspect the methods and check the documentation (hover, or F1 I think). Usually methods with exceptions are fairly obvious.

Comment: As a side note, if there's so much code in there that you regret wanting to hover and see what throws an exception, you might want to consider refactoring and extracting some things to further functions. Doesn't really help the question, though.

Comment: I tend to agree, but I'm not yet familiar enough with the project to effectively refactor it. 

And also, knowing what exceptions are thrown where would help understand and/or refactor the code, so there's a chicken and egg problem.

Comment: In my opinion you should never catch an `Exception`directly. Since Java 7 enables you to use Multicatch, you can handle all checked `Exception`s the same way. With `Exception` you catch also the `RuntimeException` which I never catch(a `RuntimeException` suggests, that you can not go on with the routine your running). You should also never throw a `RuntimeException` if you can somehow go on if the `RuntimeException` is thrown. This prevents from missing thrown `Exception`s you should deal with and can lead to serious bugs.

Comment: Why does not the trick with check occurrences work for you ? Did you fill a bug ? _Maybe there are no exceptions thrown_ ?

Comment: Have you performed a clean/rebuild? You may want to reset some state, as "Mark Occurances" *should* work.

Comment: Hi, @JustinBlank. Did you find a solution to highlight runtime exception?

Answer (score 3):

In eclipse, if you enable "highlight occurrences" and select `Exception`, it would highlight all lines that are throwing a (checked) exception that is being caught by the catch block.

Comment: Really nice feature, didn't know about it although been using Eclipse for quite a long time. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Place you cursor in the middle of the word "Exception" (or whatever type of exception you catch) in the catch clause. The word "Exception" and all method calls throwing such an exception will automatically be marked with a gray background highlighting. This feature is called "Mark occurrences" in Eclipse.

If you do not see this happen in your Eclipse installation, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> (O like Occurances) once to toggle the feature and repeat above workflow. Or use the toobar button (second entry in this [list of toolbar buttons](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/ref-java-editor.htm&cp=1_4_8)).

Answer (score -2):

You can read the class' reference manual to figure out what exception a particular method can throw. Keep in mind java has two kinds of exception: checked and unchecked. With unchecked exception, the method doesn't have to declare it can throw the exception (for example RuntimeException)

I'd also recommend you use some IDE such as Eclipse, it will instantly tell you if a line can throw exception and you're not handling it -- you can then wrap it with try-catch or have the method throw it just by single mouse click.

Comment: This really seems like you didn't read my question. I'm using eclipse and I don't want to hover over each method individually because I'm looking at a long block. Am I missing what you're saying?