# In Eclipse, how can I find Java code that throws a certain Exception?

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, code-analysis, static-analysis

When trying to understand Java code, I sometimes want to find all code where a certain custom exception (i.e. a subclass of `java.lang.Exception`) is being thrown.

To do this, in Eclipse I can use "Find References" on the Exception class. However that finds both places that *throw* and places that *catch* the exception.

Is there a way to specifically find code that throws a certain exception?

---

Related question: [Eclipse: find lines in a block that can throw exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706944/eclipse-find-lines-in-a-block-that-can-throw-exceptions)

However, that question is about finding all places in a single block of code, while my question is about finding all places across multiple classes of a project.

Comment: Maybe search for `new YourExceptionType(` or `throws YourExceptionType`

Comment: Or search for references of the contructor of the exception.

Comment: @luk2302: Yes, I considered that. However, I'd like to use a "real" code search, not a string search (which would be thrown off by things like line breaks, comments etc).

Comment: @JBNizet: Yes, good idea. However, this does not work for simple custom exceptions without an explicit constructor.

Comment: Okay, then search for the usage of the constructor(s) of your exception or general: instantiation of the class - not sure though how / if that is possible in Eclipse.

Comment: @luk2302: Yes, just found that that is possible - see my answer :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we are not talking about indirect throws like a NPE or ClassCastException, and assuming we throw a Exception right where we create the exception, you can invoke the call hierarchy of the Exception's constructor.

Eclipse's "Call Hierarchy" can not only be used on methods, but also on classes - then it will show all constructor invocations. Use the Call Hierarchy on the Exception class to find constructor invocations even in 3rd level librarys.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I edited it to clarify, hope you don't mind.

Comment: Nice - this is a shorter way to finding the same result as in my own answer. Note that the same caveats apply (as it find exception creation, not exception throwing).

Answer (score 2):

This is possible by using the ["Java Search"](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-java-search.htm), and limiting the matches to instance creations.

---

Instructions:

- open the "Java Search" (menu "Search"/"Java...", or toolbar icon)
- as the search term, enter the fully qualified name of the exception you are looking for
- "Search for": "Type"
- "Limit To": "Match locations", then in the linked detail selection, select only "Class instance creations"

---

Two limitations:

- This will also find code that creates an exception without throwing it (unusual, but possible).
- This will *not* find code that catches and then rethrows an exception - which may or may not be what you want.

*Inspired by the [similar Eclipse bug 296947](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=296947).*

Comment: I found this solution just minutes after posting the question. This goes to show how asking on SO gives you new ideas :-).

Answer (score 1):

In IntelliJ you can do a so called "Structural Search". Using this Structural Search for "new A()" does find all the 3 instantiations used below:

```
private static class A { }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new A();

    new

            A();

    new    A(


    );
}
```

[image]

https://www.quora.com/How-can-IntelliJ-style-Structural-Search-and-Replace-be-done-on-Eclipse hints at doing the same in Eclipse by doing a "simple" search with regex and using `\W` wherever possible inside the regex expression to "ignore" line breaks, whitespaces, tabs, etc. `new(\W+)A(\W*)\(` actually works quite well.

I know this is not a full answer, but maybe you can find out more knowing the term that IntelliJ uses for this purpose